# Master page but for Regions?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a RibbonBar with four buttons, each of which selects a different view and injects it into the MainRegion. Right now, it's working well but each of the four views have a few controls in common e.g. Displaying the username, date/time, search box etc. As of now, I've made separate views but I would like to know if there is a way of implementing a Master Page/UserControl so that I don't have to repeat code.

So the design, right now, is like so:

Shell

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <RibbonBar Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ToolbarRegion">
            </RibbonBar>
            <ContentControl Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion">
            </ContentControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The ToolbarRegion contains the RibbonBar with the four buttons.

Each Button will inject a view into the MainRegion. Each of these views has some common controls (much like a Master Page in ASP.Net), but the content of each view is different.

There are ways to work around this (I can't change the Shell design) but I was wondering if there was a better, more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Of course, there is such way. What did you try? Did you try to move your shared content to Master Page, and keep only actual content in sub-views?

Comment: How do you `inject a view into the MainRegion`? Which method do you use? I have very close application, and I can post basic structure, but first I need to know what do you use now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using the Prism framework, however I feel that their Regions should only be used for Application Layout (`MenuRegion`, `NavigationRegion`, `ContentRegion`, etc), and not Navigation. Using them for Navigation means letting the View control the application flow, and I feel that is a job for the ViewModels.

My preferred method for displaying changing content is with DataTemplates and ContentControls

To create something like you outlined, I would have a parent ViewModel which contains

- `ObservableCollection<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels`
- `IPageViewModel SelectedPageViewModel`

The area I wanted to display the dynamic content would use a ContentControl such as this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPage" />
```

And DataTemplates would be used to tell WPF how to draw each section

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Page1ViewModel}">
    <local:Page1View />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Page2ViewModel}">
    <local:Page2View />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Page3ViewModel}">
    <local:Page3View />
</DataTemplate>
```

I have not used a RibbonBar before, however it sounds like it should allow for an ItemsSource so your final XAML should probably look something similar to this:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <RibbonBar ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}" 
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPageViewModel}" 
                       DockPanel.Dock="Top" ...>

            </RibbonBar>

            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    ... Generic Content
                </Grid>

                <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPageViewModel}">

                    <ContentControl.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Page1ViewModel}">
                            <local:Page1View />
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Page2ViewModel}">
                            <local:Page2View />
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Page3ViewModel}">
                            <local:Page3View />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentControl.Resources>

                </ContentControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: There is easy way to move Navigation to ViewModel - by using `IRegionManager.RequestNavigate()` method. In my application I even move it to Service :)

Comment: @chopikadze I tried using `RegionManager` before and really hated it because of the confusion it caused, especially with sub regions and/or larger applications. I think its great for laying out the different regions of your application, however I don't use it for anything other than that. That's just me though :)

Comment: I tried this and checked the value of SelectedPage at runtime. It was set correctly. However, the content control did not display the view associated with the viewmodel. For the sake of testing, I did not make any changed to the Ribbonbar and simply tested this method for a single view.

Comment: @DukeCyrillus Does `SelectedPage` raise a PropertyChange notification when the value changes? Your class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you'll need to raise the PropertyChanged notification for WPF to automatically update the UI

Comment: I'm slightly confused here... is SelectedPage a View (i.e. UserControl) or a ViewModel? The Content of a ContentControl should be a UserControl instead of a ViewModel, right? When I debug and check the value of SelectedPage in the XAML, it shows the correct value. I did try raising the Property Changed event as well. It didn't work.

Comment: @DukeCyrillus Perhaps I used a bad variable name. `SelectedPage` is a ViewModel. By binding `ContentControl.Content` to the ViewModel, we are inserting the ViewModel in the VisualTree, and the DataTemplate is telling WPF that anytime it encounters an object of type `Page1ViewModel` in the Visual Tree, it should draw it using `Page1View`.

Comment: @Rachel This was my understanding as well but for some strange reason, even when SelectedPage is being assigned the correct value (IViewModel), and there is just the one DataTemplate with DataType as ViewModel (which implements IViewModel), it is not drawing the corresponding view.

Comment: @DukeCyrillus Are you getting anything displayed at all? By default WPF displays a TextBlock with the full class name of an object if it doesn't have a DataTemplate for it. If you are not getting the full class name displayed in your ContentControl, then the binding is the problem. If you are, then the DataTemplate is the problem.

Comment: @Rachel Nothing is being displayed. The problem is that when I debug and check if the SelectedPage is being assigned the proper value, I find that it is so I'm not sure why the view isn't being shown.

Comment: Ugh! I forgot to set the DataContext >.< Now the full class name is being displayed, so the binding is fine.

Comment: @DukeCyrillus Glad that worked out :) For debugging binding errors, I'd highly recommend installing Snoop: http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ Its a free tool for debugging WPF applications, and I use it all the time

Answer (score 1):

Content of your `Shell.xaml`:

```
<Window ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <!-- Your shared content -->
        </Grid>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is what I was doing but I failed to mention that I already have a shell and the four views that I have will each be injected into the MainRegion, meaning I can make another region in a UserControl (which will be injected into the MainRegion) but in order to inject views into this SubRegion, I would have to have reference these sub-views in the RibbonBar control (which is in another Region of the Shell). I'll update my question to try to make it clearer.